# How to remove <hash></hash> from format.xml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an object that `has_many` child objects that should be rendered as xml. This is not a problem. My Problem is that I creat a `Hash` containing this data like the parser needs it. But rails atomaticly encloses the whole file with

```
<hash>
    <objects type="array">
        <object>
           ...
           ...
           ...
        </object>
    </objects>
</hash>
```

I need to get rid of the `type="array"` and the `<hash>` how can I handle this? I didnt find anything on the documentation.

Comment: Have you tried `to_xml` method? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739905/how-do-i-convert-a-ruby-hash-to-xml

Comment: Looks like this is exactly your case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241911/rails-rendering-xml-adds-hash-tag

Comment: Thank you that did a part I found the rest on my own => `:skip_types => true`

Comment: @davidb post it like an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render :xml => @objects.to_xml(:root => :root_name, :skip_types => true)
```

Comment: Now I have the tag <root-name> in my output xml... Not the intent of the question as I read it. The "array" is gone, but <hash> is just renamed.. it's still just as there.

Comment: looks fine:? [1,2,3].to_xml(:root => :objects, :skip_types => true)
 => "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<objects>\n  <object>1</object>\n  <object>2</object>\n  <object>3</object>\n</objects>\n"

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same Issue;

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contacts>
  <Contact type="array">
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

I was using this:

```
entries.to_xml
```

to convert hash data into XML, but this wraps entries' data into `<hash></hash>`

So I modified:

```
entries.to_xml(root: "Contacts")
```

but that still wrapped the converted XML in 'Contacts' modifying my XML code to

```
<Contacts>
 <Contacts>
  <Contact type="array">
   <Contact>
    <Name></Name>
    <Email></Email>
    <Phone></Phone>
   </Contact>
  </Contact>
 </Contacts>
</Contacts>
```

So it adds an extra ROOT that I don't wan't there.

**Now solution to this what worked for me is:**

```
 entries["Contacts"].to_xml(root: "Contacts")
```

that avoids `<hash></hash>` or any additional root to be included.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of reasons when doing actual development in the actual world why you might need fragments of XML **even if you're perfectly well aware that the actual XML spec dictates a single root**.

However, the ActiveSupport's `Hash#to_xml` does not support this.

Here is a method which does (add in `config/initializers/rootless_xml.rb`):

```
class Hash
  def to_rootless_xml(options = {})
    require 'active_support/builder' unless defined?(Builder)

    options = options.dup
    options[:indent]  ||= 2
    options[:root]    ||= 'hash'
    options[:builder] ||= Builder::XmlMarkup.new(indent: options[:indent])

    builder = options[:builder]
    builder.instruct! unless options.delete(:skip_instruct)


    each { |key, value| ActiveSupport::XmlMini.to_tag(key, value, options) }
    yield builder if block_given?
    builder.target!
  end
end
```